# Generate a tree from a text file using python

Tags: python-2.7

I Have a txt file which has data like this:

```
arp
show
show ip
show ip route
show ip route static
show ip default-gateway
show ip default-gateway static
show ip interface
show partition
no
no logging
no logging on
no logging override
```

I have to print a tree in the following way:

```
arp
show 
     ip
        route
                          static
        default-gateway

                           static
        interface
      partition
no
      logging
                  on
                  override
```

Thanks in advance for the help!!!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry, had to minus one as it does not seem like you even tried to solve this yourself.  We are not here to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The count of words - 1 indicates tab depth.  Loop through each line and prepend a tab using this heuristic in combination with pulling only word X for display.